# Scraping from javascript using Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I need to scrape the content with javascript tag using scrapy as follows:

```
<script type='text/javascript' id='script-id'> attribute={"pid":"123","title":"abc","url":"http://example.com","date":"2014-07-31 14:56:39 CDT","channels":["test"],"tags":[],"authors":["james Catcher"]};</script>
```

I can extract the content using xpath

```
response.xpath('id("script-id")//text()').extract()
```

Output

```
[u'\nattribute = {"pid":"123","title":"abc","url":"http:/example.com","date":"2014-07-30 15:34:10 ","channels":["test"],"tags":[],"authors":["james Watt"]};\n(function( ){\n var s = document.createElement(\'script\');\n s.async = true;\n s.type = \'text/javascript\';\n s.src = document.location.protocol + \'//d8rk54i4mohrb. cloudfront.net/js/reach.js\';\n (document.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName(\'body\')[0]).appendChild(s);\n})();\n'']
```

How can I get each values using xpath?

Comment: @Artjom B. now i edited the question, how can i get values of pid, title etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is json, so you can first extract it from the string, then load it with json

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: sample_string = [u'\n attribute={"pid":"123","title":"abc",'
        +'"url":"http:/example.com","date":"2014-07-30 15:34:10 ",'
        +'"channels":["test"],"tags":[],"authors":["james Watt"]}'][0]

In [3]: data = json.loads(sample_string[12:])

In [4]: data
Out[4]:
{u'authors': [u'james Watt'],
u'channels': [u'test'],
u'date': u'2014-07-30 15:34:10 ',
u'pid': u'123',
u'tags': [],
u'title': u'abc',
u'url': u'http:/example.com'}

In [5]: data['authors']
Out[5]: [u'james Watt']
```

Alternatively, you can also load a javascript engine like PyV8 to interpret those variables.

Comment: The output also has following:[u'\nscript-id = {"pid":"123","title":"abc","url":"http:/example.com","date":"2014-07-30 15:34:10 ","channels":["test"],"tags":[],"authors":["james Watt"]}];\n(function(
){\n  var s = document.createElement(\'script\');\n  s.async = true;\n  s.type =
 \'text/javascript\';\n  s.src = document.location.protocol + \'//d8rk54i4mohrb.
cloudfront.net/js/reach.js\';\n  (document.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0] ||
document.getElementsByTagName(\'body\')[0]).appendChild(s);\n})();\n']

Comment: I think it is better to use `output.split("attribute=")[1]` instead of splicing (`[13:]`). Or even better `output.split("=")[1]`

Comment: Yep, completely fine as well. Whatever works based on the type of strings encountered.