# How can I identify a js array by its keys?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

My spider returns javascript code as a string. From this code I need to retrieve an array which I can identify by its keys.

That means, I already have the keys but how do I get the complete array? Also, I don't know the name of the array.

Is regex suitable? Or is there a good way to achieve this?
Thanks!

EDIT:

Well part of the javacode looks like this (sorry, but it's is too much and unessential to copy everything into here):

```
 {var P=parseInt($(".secondary-results-count").html());if(P-1<1){$(".secondary-results-show").hide()}else{$(".secondary-results-count").html(P-1)}}},hasOffers:function(M){if(M.result.offer&&M.result.offer.offers){return(M.result.offer.offers.length>0)?true:false}return false},queryCompanyInfo:function(O,M,N){new QueryCompanyInfo({companyInfoId:O,bookingId:M},function(Q){if(Q.status=="Ok"){var P=arrayStore.inst("offersId");var R=P.get(M);R.company=Q.result.companyInfo;P.put(M,R);if(N){N(Q,P.get(M))}}}).query()},createOfferHtml:function(O){arrayStore.inst("offersId").put(O.bookingId,{price:O,company:null});var aq={"-2":"Best Value","-3":"Executive","-4":"Minibus","-1":"Other","0":"NotSet","1":"Compact","2":"Sedan","3":"PeopleCarrier","4":"SUV","5":"VanOrMinibus","6":"Coach","7":"StretchLimo","8":"StationWagon","9":"Convertible","102":"SportsCar","104":"Offroad","105":"PickupTruck","106":"Motorcycle","107":"Rickshaw","108":"WaterTaxi"};var Z=12; ...
```

And I do know the keys "-1", "-2", "-3".

Comment: Please improve your question by adding the string and telling what part(s) of the string you are interested in and what you've tried already to get there. Your question is imho to broad and could be answered with: "Yes, regex is fine".

Comment: Have a look at this [so question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071994/scraping-from-javascript-using-scrapy)

Comment: The problem is that this is just a snippet from the code and it's a string. Maybe you could help with regex? Because I couldn't figure out how to

Comment: Then create a new question with a minimum example of your string, your regex, what you get and what you expect. Please don't expect me to do the work because you don't want to do it.

Comment: Sorry that you took it that way but I asked for advice, not that you do my work.
I have this regex and it works now `(\{[^\{\}\(\)]*\"-1\".*\})`. I just thought there might be a more elegent solution ...

Answer (score 0):

well first of all i would suggest you its not related to scrapy question,

On the other hand you can grab this data using regex

i tried `var\s+aq=(.*?);` regex and its working perfectly fine for your problem

Comment: thanks, the only problem is that the array might be called differently

Answer (score 0):

You can use [js2xml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/js2xml) for this, and identify the object using an XPath like this:

```
>>> import js2xml 
>>> jstree = js2xml.parse(jsstring) 
>>> objs = jstree.xpath('//object[property[@name = "-1"]]')
>>> # or this alternative
>>> # objs = jstree.xpath('//object[property/@name="-1"]')
>>> print js2xml.jsonlike.make_dict(objs[0])
... {'-1': 'Other',
...  '-2': 'Best Value',
...  '-3': 'Executive',
...  '-4': 'Minibus',
...  '0': 'NotSet',
...  '1': 'Compact',
...  '102': 'SportsCar',
...  '104': 'Offroad',
...  '105': 'PickupTruck',
...  '106': 'Motorcycle',
...  '107': 'Rickshaw',
...  '108': 'WaterTaxi',
...  '2': 'Sedan',
...  '3': 'PeopleCarrier',
...  '4': 'SUV',
...  '5': 'VanOrMinibus',
...  '6': 'Coach',
...  '7': 'StretchLimo',
...  '8': 'StationWagon',
...  '9': 'Convertible'}
```